# Animate the search list when typing on the searchbar (React)

Tags: reactjs, sass

What I'm trying to do:
When a character is written in the search bar, the section is updated automatically after 0,8 sec of inaction (not typing), with the results corresponding to the research. The results appear with a slide effect to the top. The filters that do not match the research disappear with a fade out effect.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const users = [
    { name: "Jack", id: "1" },
    { name: "Lisa", id: "2" },
    { name: "Peter", id: "3" },
    { name: "Roman", id: "4" },
    { name: "Sarah", id: "5" },
    { name: "Eric", id: "6" },
    { name: "Fiora", id: "7" },
  ];

  const filterNames = ({ name }) => {
    return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <SearchBar onSearch={setSearchValue} value={searchValue} />
      <ul>
        {users.filter(filterNames).map((user) => (
          <li className="user" key={user.id}>
            {user.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar

```
import React from "react";

function SearchBar(props) {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => props.onSearch(e.target.value)}
      value={props.value}
    />
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

App.scss

```
.user {
  list-style: none;
  animation: slide-in-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

@keyframes slide-in-bottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

fade out effect

```
animation: fade-out 1s ease-out both;
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I tried to add the slide in animation to the 'li' with className user but the animation only works in the first render and not when I type on the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

> Main issue with your code flow is, that you are removing elements,
>
> **how does someone can apply the css on removed element**,
>
> you need that element to give animation first,

So here is what you can do

```
// remove this

//   const filterNames = ({ name }) => {
//     return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
//   };

return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <SearchBar onSearch={setSearchValue} value={searchValue} />
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => {
          // we can use it as like
          let classname = user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? 'user' : 'user removed';
          return <li className={classname} key={user.id}>
            {user.name}
          </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
);
```

And add some css for not matched user, to give removing effect.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-remove-animation?file=index.js)**

Comment: Thanks man, and how can I add the slide in from bottom to top when I search, after 0.8s second the result should slide to the top and those who dont match should be removed.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: you can all do that in css with delay option, I have updated the demo with fadeout effect, please check @YassineAb

Comment: When a character is written in the search bar, the section is updated automatically after 0,8 sec, with the results corresponding to the research. The results appear with a slide effect to the top, Thats what I meant

Comment: I think the question is already solved, SO doesn't work this way, first you need to try to solve by your self, if that doesn't work then you can ask another question. please accept the answer also @YassineAb